# Using enumerate inside a generator

Tags: python

I had an assignment:

> Given a list in variable `x`, write a one-line Python generator
>   expression that returns only the elements from x that are odd integers
>   or have an even (zero-based) index in `x`. The given list may contain
>   items other than numbers. The solution must be a generator expression.

I wrote this working solution

```
def is_odd_integer(item):
    if type(item) is int:
        return item % 2 != 0
    return False

def is_even(index):
    return index % 2 == 0

def get_odd_integers_or_even_index(list):
    for index, item in enumerate(list):
        if is_odd_integer(item) or is_even(index):
           yield item


for item in get_odd_integers_or_even_index([1,2,5,6,'sdf', '12',5,4,3,4,4,4,4]):
    print(item)
```

Does using `enumerate` inside of a python generator defeat its purpose? If yes, how would you implement this?

Comment: I don't see any generator expression.

Comment: read up on "generator expression"s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[v for i, v in enumerate(x) if ((type(v) is int and v % 2 == 1) or i % 2 == 0)]
```

Edit:
Edited solution to match coditions
[See it working at rextester.](http://rextester.com/ZIC95907)

Comment: another condition `i % 2 == 0`

Comment: @Andomar if this considered a python generator? I think not. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It is a generator expression

Comment: @sureshvv: on reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression), the above is a list comprehension. You can turn it into a generator by replacing `[]` with `()`.

Comment: It is list comprehension not a generating expression

Comment: I would use "isinstance(v, int)" rather than "type(v) is int"

Comment: @sureshvv: Why is one better than the other?

Comment: isinstance will work with derived classes also since it is not looking for an exact match of type.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = (item for item in x if (isinstance(item, int) and not item%2==0)
                                or x.index(item)%2==0)
```

Generator expressions are similar to writing "tuple comprehensions" and are of the format:

```
generator = ( item for item in iterable if condition)
```

Since, the questions specifically asks you to write a one-liner generator expression, you can use the above line. However, in terms writing *Pythonic* code, I would suggest you separate out the computation of odd numbers to a lambda function such as:

```
is_odd = lambda x: x%2 == 1
results = (item for item in x if (isinstance(item, int) and is_odd(item))
                                  or not is_odd(x.index(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression). Since you need access to the list's index, you could start from a `range` expression and use it to evaluate the index, or access the list's item via the `[]` operator:

```
(lst[i] for i in range(0, len(lst)) if (i % 2 == 0) or (isinstance(lst[i], int) and lst[i] % 2 == 1))
```

Whether or not this syntax is nicer than your attempt is in the eye of the beholder, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `enumerator` can be used inside `generator` here is sample with input and outputs:-

## Input

```
x = [1,2,5,6,'sdf', '12',5,4,3,4,4,11,4]
```

## Enumerator and Generator

```
y = (value for index, value in enumerate(x) if type(value) is int and (value % 2 == 1 or index %2 == 0))
```

## Output

```
print (list(y))
[1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: `value % 2 == 1` he wants odd numbers